# Ele me/mim deu - dúvida com pronomes indiretos

Tags: pronomes

Bom dia!

Sou brasileiro nativo e fluente em inglês e estou aprendendo francês. Como eu estudo idiomas por meios gramaticais, estava fazendo uma comparação com português/inglês/francês nos pronomes pessoais diretos e indiretos e cheguei a um questionamento:

Por que dizemos: "*Ele me deu o livro*" e não "*Ele mim deu o livro*" considerando que se trocássemos a estrutura para: "*Ele deu o livro para mim*" obteríamos "*mim*" ao invés de "*me*", logo, entendo que "*me/mim*" em ambas as orações estão agindo como objetos indiretos.

Cheguei à conclusão de que quando utilizamos a estrutura reduzida para objetos diretos e indiretos, tais como: *Ele me deu, Ela lhe entregou o livro, Nós te achamos*, ao invés da forma extensa: *Ela entregou o livro para ele*..., não devemos utilizar o objeto indireto na sua forma indireta, mas sim na sua forma direta. Este meu raciocínio é lógico?

Também cheguei à conclusão de que no português, só existem 2 formas de pronomes objetivos indiretos: *Eu (Mim) e Tu (Ti)*

Comment: Sinceramente, não consegui compreender muito bem. No seu raciocínio, deveríamos falar, por exemplo: "Ela mim entregou o livro"?

Comment: Basicamente, considerando que ao inverter a estrutura, obteríamos: Ele deu para MIM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os pronomes *mim* e *ti* não são pronomes oblíquos **indiretos** porque não são pronomes **clíticos**. São pronomes tónicos e, portanto, são usados somente após uma preposição.

Os pronomes *oblíquos* subdividem-se em dois tipos distintos:

1. Os pronomes oblíquos ***átonos*** (ou seja clíticos), tanto diretos como indiretos, **nunca** precedidos de preposição:
   *me, te, se, o, a, lhe, nos, vos, se, os, as, lhes.*
2. Os pronomes oblíquos ***tónicos***, **sempre** precedidos de preposição:
   ***mim, ti**, si, ele, ela, nós, vós, si, eles, elas*.

No português, existe apenas uma distinção morfológica entre
pronomes diretos e indiretos na terceira pessoa, nunca na primeira ou
na segunda. É o mesmo no espanhol, francês, italiano e catalão.

Por outro lado, existe uma diferença entre caso acusativo e caso dativo
nos pronomes latinos e alemães, mas não em pronomes ingleses ou nos
idiomas românicos modernos.

Comment: Interessante a explicação. Obrigado.
Outra dúvida: você também participa do fórum de Inglês, correto? Sua proficiência nos idiomas e conhecimento são invejáveis.